# Import Database IMPDP - Different Versions

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

We are having oracle installed in 2 different servers.

**Server 1: Oracle Version Details**

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

**Server 2: Oracle Version Details**

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

I need to import a database backup from Server 1 to Server 2. I have tried this.

**Export From Server 1:**

```
EXPDP Username/Password@xe DIRECTORY=CUSTOM_DIR SCHEMAS=PRICE DUMPFILE=PRICE.DMP
```

**Import To Server 2:**

```
IMPDP Username/Password@\"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Test)(PORT=1500)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TESTSID)))\" DIRECTORY=CUSTOM_DIR DUMPFILE=TEST.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE LOGFILE=TEST.LOG
```

While importing, i am getting the exception as,

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.2.0.1.0
```

Is that not possible to import the backups between different versions.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You need to supply the "version" parameter on the export, and specify 11.2.0.1.  This will instruct expdp to create a dmp file that is compatible with that version.  See [expdp command reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1006293)

Comment: Also for future reference, these types of questions (non-programming) should be posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sure in future i will use stackexchange.

Comment: I have tried VERSION - COMPATIBLE, VERSION - LATEST, VERSION - 11.1, VERSION - 11.2, VERSION - 10.2....Still Facing the same issue...I have tried this in IMPDP as well as in EXPDP.

Comment: Still issue is there. Any ideas.?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use **Oracle Database 12g Data Pump** to import dump file inside a **Oracle 11g Database**. The return i got was UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.2.0.4.0 .

The cause is: Two Oracle Homes in different versions, and the expdp/impdp called is wrong (verify path variable).

This may be occuring with you. You have another $ORACLE_HOME in your environment, and the data pump called is from this environment. Verify your .bash_profile or .profile files and set the correct environment.